# Cors error on Angular Form data upload to Cloudinary

Tags: angular, cors

Hi I am trying to upoload images to cloudinary api from my localhost angular application and get the following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxxxx/image/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

My angular form and http request :

```
<input type="file" #file (change)="onChange(file.files)" multiple />
```

```
onChange(files: FileList) {
    this.files = Object.values(files);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Type': 'formData'
    });

    for (let file of this.files) {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', file);
      data.append('upload_preset', 'pics');

      this.http
        .post(
          'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxxxxxx/image/upload',
          file,
          {
            headers
          }
        )
        .subscribe(
          resData => {
            console.log(resData);
          },
          errorMessage => {
            console.log(errorMessage);
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `'Type': 'formData'` header setting from your frontend JavaScript code?

Comment: Removing the  complete header information worked! Looks like angular configured the header information?

Answer (score 0):

CROS Cross Origin Issue - unable to connect with database
When API is called -> request is unable to reach API server

usually in Case when some API method requires 2 parameters (name,image)
but in angular application we called Post method & passed single parameter to it (name)

Here for images Upload/Update - postImages() - no header Content-Type
instead of post()

DONT stringify image -> bytes will be lost (Make new Post route:postImages)

dataService:

[image]

header_interceptor:

[image]

Component calling API (upload image + add name from Form -> API)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is three solution for this issue:

1. disable cors policy from server-side
2. disable cors in the browser, for example for google chrome https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/
3. create a proxy file and through that connect to the server

proxy.json

```
  "/api/**": {
    "target": {
      "host": "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxxxxxx/image/upload",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 80
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: '/api/alpha/v1',
};
```

and run angular with below command

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json -o
```